# unable to identify what is the below script for in SharePoint 2013 master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Scrolling through the master page, I found a piece of code, which I am not able to identify, it was for. Can someone help me in it?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var g_pageLoadAnimationParams = { elementSlideIn : "sideNavBox", elementSlideInPhase2 : "contentBox" };

    //]]>
```